# How to bake Displacement's Height and Scale?

Tags: shaders, displacement

There was this shader that I have been trying to bake the displacement map and see if it's gonna work out but all it's doing is baking the displacement "Height" only. The reason why I am trying to bake this is because if it is not baked then the outcome will look like this:
[image]

I am trying to make this look like this: (which is what it looks like when rendered)
[image]

This is what happens when I try to bake its displacement: (I used a displacement modifier)
[image]

Now I believed that all its baking is the Height of the Displacement and it's not considering the Scale of it. The result is similar to when I bake it when tried removing it.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what your baking setup is but you can very clearly see that those aren't even close to the same image. It looks like the object you were baking from is way displaced from the surface of your low poly object. The whole image is almost 100% white. I would recommend trying to rebake with the "low poly object" somewhere halfway between the lowest parts of the displacement and highest parts.

Comment: I cannot clearly see your node setup because it's too small and parts are outside the scrennshot, I also don't know how you're baking the texture. The only thing I immediately realize is that there is a _Mix RGB_ node set to _Add_ with _Clamp_ disabled. Clamping limits the RGB values to the 0 to 1 range. Adding, subtracting, multiplying, dividing colors without clamping can produce values above 1 or below 0. If you then bake the texture to a PNG or JPG file, all the values outside the 0 to 1 range will then be lost. So baking these values would require a file format like EXR for example.